# Android: can't refresh my listview

Tags: android

When I try to delete an item in a listview it does not update then the listview. I have followed and read some similar questions here in stackoverflow but I had no results. Can you please help me?

I have an Activity Ver where I have an onResume() method:

```
public class Ver_DespesasActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private ListView listView ;
private ArrayAdapter dataAdapter;
private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper ;
private List<Despesa> despesas;
ArrayList<Despesa>items;
MyAdapter adapter;

(...)
  @Override
  public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            databaseHelper= new DatabaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
            Gasto gasto = databaseHelper.getGasto();
            String mes = gasto.getMes();
            int ano = gasto.getAno();

            items.clear();
            items.addAll(databaseHelper.getAllDespesas(mes, ano));
            adapter.refresh(items);
    }
```

Then I have a class MyAdapter where I have the refresh() method:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Despesa> list = new ArrayList<Despesa>();
    private Context context;
(...)
public void refresh(ArrayList<Despesa> list)
    {
        this.list = list;
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

**MyAdapterConstructor:**

```
public MyAdapter(ArrayList list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }
```

**Update:** I don't know if this is important, I'm not using list.remove to remove the items of my listview, I have a method mine to do it.

Comment: Can you just test purpose change this line, `private ArrayList<Despesa> list = new ArrayList<Despesa>();` with `private ArrayList<Despesa> list;` and test your code? As i have doubt of your `list` is newly created not refers to `item`.

Comment: @user370305 same result :\

Comment: If you are not creating new instance of `private ArrayList<Despesa> list` using `new` and giving reference of `items` (as ArrayList items cleared and again added new entry). Then it has to work.

Comment: Post your MyAdapter constructor.

Comment: @karaokyo I've updated the question with the construtor

Comment: @karaokyo please check my last comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the adapter is already using your `items` list, you don't need your refresh method. You can just modify the items as you are doing and directly `notifyDataSetChanged`.

```
items.clear();
items.addAll(databaseHelper.getAllDespesas(mes, ano));
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: if I do this my listview doesn't appear. I'm doing the clear() in the Activity which I think is also possible.

Comment: is `items` the list that you pass into your `MyAdapter` constructor?

Comment: Thanks for the update, I updated my answer accordingly, assuming that your `MyAdapter` constructor is passed the `items` list.

Comment: well it works but not as I expected, I mean when you use list.remove it removes the item instantly, here it removes the item but I have to exit the list go back to my Ver Activity and return to my list, do you understand what I'm saying?

Comment: If you want to address an issue with your remove, you should post the code for it. I really think you should be using list.remove(). What is your reason for not doing so?

Comment: I have 2 tables, every time I remove a row from one I have to update a column from the other table...so I have a method to do both, the DELETE and the UPDATE..with list.remove I couldn't do it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71718/discussion-between-porthfind-and-karaokyo).